# how to convert PS response into pdf file using Node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pdf, postscript

I get response from a CURL request like below

```
5 0 obj <</BaseFont/Helvetica/Type/Font/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/Subtype/Type1>> ........   7 0 obj <</Type/XObject/Resources<</ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]/Font<</F1 5 0 R>>>>/Subtype/Form/BBox[0 70 95 100]/Matrix [1 0 0 1 0 0]/Length 80/FormType 1/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream x�s �2T0^@BC^E#^E^KS=c^S��\.}7C^EC#=33��4.�����ĒҢT^E��<12>,$^]�@E� ^]^Za�E�i��) y�^P.^@v�^UT endstream
```

I try to convert the above resposne into pdf using below node js code

```
var data = readFile_fun();  //Get post script response from function  
fs.writeFile("pdf.pdf", data, 'binary', async function (err) {
  if (err) {
      console.log("=====err===========");
      console.log(err);
      return_data.success = false
      return_data.message = err
      return res.json(return_data)
  }
});
```

This generate a pdf file. but, when i try to open the file,it show me a error

> File type plain text document (text/plain) is not supported

Please give me a solution to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please put the code for `readFile_fun()`, atleast an example.

Comment: exec("curl -X POST 'http://192.168.15.1:8200/clickfin/AuthnRequest?' -d 'usr_id=abcd", (err, stdout, stderr) => { if (err) {console.log(stderr);}else{ return 
 stdout } });  @AritraChakraborty

Comment: What you have quoted (probably) isn't PostScript, its PDF. Though it could be that its a PDF file translated into PostScript. If it is PostScript then its missing all of the header of the program and is unusable. I suspect its not PostScript at all, it looks to me like a PDF file with lots of bits missing (header, trailer, xref table, Pages tree, metadata) Of course you seem to have elided shunks of it, so its possible the missing bits are in the missing section.